# Meaning of ST and OP fields in dumpsys netstats output

Tags: android, networking, adb, dumpsys

I am running the `adb shell dumpsys netstats detail` command to obtain details of the network usage, however, I do not know the meaning of all the acronyms that has the result of this command.

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys) of the dumpsys tool they explain the meaning of **rb**, **rp**, **tb** and **tp**, but not that of ***st*** or ***op***.

Anyone know what it means?

This is a fragment of command output.

```
defaultNetwork=true}] uid=10127 set=DEFAULT tag=0x0
    NetworkStatsHistory: bucketDuration=3600
      st=1567522800 rb=1275 rp=5 tb=876 tp=5 op=0
      st=1567526400 rb=6697 rp=41 tb=7359 tp=38 op=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`st` is the `bucketStart` timestamp and `op` is number of `operations`.

Comment: Thank you so much
In this context, what is the bucketStart?

Comment: Quite obviously the `bucketStart` is a timestamp when the specific `bucket` has started.